# What should be the text in a "Go" button in a Spanish application?

Tags: traducción

I am translating an application from English to Spanish. One of the English buttons in the app is <kbd>go</kbd>, which sends the user from my app to Uber to call an Uber car.

What is the common Spanish text for a <kbd>go</kbd> button? Is <kbd>ir</kbd> a good choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, `ir` is a perfect choice, since you are actually sending the user from one place/page to another.

Comment: Thanks! Is the convention for buttons `ir` or `Ir`, please?

Comment: Probably you'll se more "Ir" than "ir" but the key is actually to be consistent in your app. If the other buttons' caption start with lowercase just use "ir".